# 2 parametrizations can be linked by a deffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

Define a parametrized curve as $r:(a,b)\to\Bbb R^3$ be $C^\infty$. It is clear that a curve can have different parametrizations. Say, $(u-v)t+u$ and $(v-u)t+v:t\in(0,1)$ parametrized the same line segment connecting $u,v$.

I am learning elementary differential geometry. I got a definition of reparametrization of a curve as a composition of a curve and a deffeomorphism. i.e if $r:(a,b)\to\Bbb R^3$ is a curve, a reparametrization is a $r \circ \phi:(c,d)\to \Bbb R^3$, where $\phi:(c,d)\to (a,b)$ is a deffeomorphism.

I am wondering if $r,l$ are parametrizations of a curve $C$, is it necessary for $r$ to be a reprarametrizaiton of $l$? for example, $(u-v)t+u$= $(v-u)\phi(t)+v:t\in(0,1)$, where $\phi(t)=1-t$. But I have trouble finding $\phi$ for general curves.

Comment: ok. edited. thank you @Bernstein

Comment: I think you have to understand one thing a parametrized  diff curve is the map and not the image (which is the set ),  a segment in R^3 you can have different parameterization for these segment with no diffeomorphism between the two parameterizations, and to avoid these in DG we adopt the parameterization by arcs length

Comment: Yes, I understand that a curve refers to a set of points. But for your second statement, do you have an counter example?@Bernstein

Comment: Arclength parametrization is not really relevant. All that you need for this discussion is regular parametrizations, i.e., parametrizations with non-vanishing velocity. We do not need constant speed or constant speed $1$. Of course, arclength parametrizations are important whenever we want to measure something *intrinsic* to the curve, rather than the parametrization.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you for your comment. I saw your comment in the answer that the result is valid if the curve is required to be a regular curve, do you have any hint for me to construct a such $\phi$?

Comment: Sure: Just look at $r^{-1}\circ l$. With the regularity assumption, these are both diffeomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a counterexample given by two parametrizations of the first factor $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely

$$r:x\mapsto (x^3,0,0)\text{ and }l:x\mapsto (x,0,0).$$

If there is a diffeomorphism $\varphi$ such that $l=r\circ\varphi$, i.e. $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, x=\varphi(x)^3$, then $\varphi(\bullet)=\sqrt[3]{\bullet}$. But this latter is not a diffeomorphism, since it is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: It's worth commenting that when the parametrizations are *regular* (nowhere-zero derivative), then the result is valid.